# Log transformations of function domain and inequalities

Tags: functions, logarithms, convex-optimization

If I know that for some function $f$, the following is true for $x, y \geq 0$:

$f(\log (x^a y^b)) \leq f(\log x)^a f(\log y)^b$

Can I make the claim that

$f(x^a y^b) \leq f(x)^a f(y)^b$

If I cannot generally, are there certain conditions under which I can make this claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't think so.
Taking log x = p & log y = q.

You can write it as

$f(ap + bq) \leq f(p)^a  f(q)^b$

Now replace p and q by x and y.

Comment: Thanks much! This seems correct.